# Why is my password programme code not working?

Tags: python, passwords

The code will only let me guess once . Can someone please tell me what is wrong with my code?

Challenge:

> Write a program that sets a password as ‘Gain Access ’ and asks the
>   user to enter the password and keeps asking until the correct password
>   is entered and then says ‘Accepted’. The program should count how many
>   attempts the user has taken and tell them after they have been
>   accepted.

```
enter code here
password = 'Gain access'
count = 0
input = input("Enter the password: \n")

while input != password:
    print("Incorrect password! Please try again: \n")
    count = count + 1
    print("You have now got your password wrong " + str(count) + " times. \n")

    if(count < 5):
        print("Access denied, please contact security to reset your password.")
        break
    else:
        print("Accepted, welcome back.")
        print("You had " + str(count) + " attempts until you got your password right.")
```

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: Python is the language that is being used .

Comment: Also include the output of the console in such a case. I assume that it outputs "Access denied" 5 times in a row really quickly when you enter a wrong password initially?

Answer (score 1):

You should always include the language you're programming in like simonwo mentioned already.

Looks like Python to me though. I suppose this line `input = input("Enter the password: \n")` needs to go after `while input != password:`, as well. Otherwise you can only enter the password once and then it directly executes all 5 loops. But you should NOT assign `input` because this is the function you want to obtain the input from.

Do something like `user_input = input("Enter the password: \n")`. So your code should look something like this:

```
...
user_input = input("Enter the password: \n")

while user_input != password:
    print("Incorrect password! Please try again: \n")
    user_input = input("Enter the password: \n")
    ... Your existing code here
```

But note that this way the user won't get notified if they entered the correct password with their first try. You could insert a check after the first reading of the user input and if it matches the desired password print your welcome phrase.

Comment: Thank you and sorry this is my first post .

Comment: No problem, that's why we give you hints how to improve your question :) Did my suggestion solve your issue?

Comment: I'm glad I could help! I'd be thankful if you could accept my answer as correct by clicking the tick underneath the up- and downvote buttons :)